Kafka Connect docker image not recognizing AWS environment variable credentials?
I'm currently learning Kafka Connect on my own by trying to set up some basic pipelines in Docker. The main issue is that it appears that when I try to use the connect REST API to spin up a new connector with a POST request, no errors appear right away. However, when sending a request to the status endpoint for the connector I get an error that states "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: with a list of all the places that AWS looks for credentials. My config + curl for the connector looks like the following:
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
    "name": "S3Connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
        "flush.size": "1",
        "name": "S3Connector", 
        "topics": "inputTopic",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "s3.bucket.name": "bucket-name-here",
        "s3.region": "us-east-2",
        "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
        "s3.credentials.provider.secret_access_key": "secret-access-key-here",
        "s3.credentials.provider.access_key_id": "access-key-id-here",
        "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.bytearray.ByteArrayFormat",
        
    }
}' http://localhost:8083/connectors

I initially attempted to just use the s3.credentials config lines to pass in the AWS credentials, but got this error. At that point, I attempted to manually set the environment variables listed in the error with values set to the two keys in the config above using export. When I deleted the connector and tried to recreate it, I get the same issue. Why would it have trouble reading the keys when they're in place?
Update: So setting the environment variable in docker-compose seems to have fixed this. I am assuming that the confluent hub install for the S3 connector (in this case confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3:latest) somehow uses what are supposed to be the existing environment variables at the time of install but can't pick them up once it's already installed without some update of a separate config inside the install?

Tip - you can use minio container for a local s3


use the s3.credentials config lines

You don't need the provider prefix for those - https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/s3-sink/current/configuration_options.html

using export

Docker doesn't read your exported shell environment by default

setting the environment variable in docker-compose seems to have fixed this

Yes, this is the correct solution

somehow uses what are supposed to be the existing environment variables at the time of install

This is not the case. The AWS SDK is only invoked when you actually create the connector, not install it

I managed to figure out the provider prefix was unnecessary shortly after my update! I am wondering why setting export env variables inside of the docker container with bash doesn't work though. Does Docker only read the environment variables from a certain file that is created from the docker-compose without allowing in-container updates? I appreciate the help!

setting export env variables inside of the docker container with bash doesn't work - Because the JVM process is already running and would need restarted (which would restart the container, and lose those variables). Therefore you need to add them via Compose or docker run -e, when the container process starts.

That makes sense, I'm obviously not super well versed in Docker either and have been learning it as I go. Your github repos have helped me a ton already before I ever posted this question so thanks a ton
